# Excel 2013 VBA ShellExecute with search box initialized

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

Using the following code:

```
Option Explicit 
 'API declaration for the windows "Search Results" dialog
Private Declare Function ShellSearch& Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
ByVal nShowCmd As Long)

Private Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1


Sub ShowWindowsSearchDialog_API()
     '   Specified drive to Search
    Const szSDrive As String = "C:\"

    ShellSearch 0, "find", szSDrive, "", "", SW_SHOWNORMAL
End Sub
```

It opens the search dialog box in explorer at the spot I want it to just peachy.

But how do I pre-initialize the search parameters? The 4th option is supposed to be some kind of parameter list, but I could only find c++ documentation on msdn, and it didn't read like it was an option.  I've tried a couple variations, but nothing seems to take.  I hate the thoughts of using something like sendkeys.  Not even sure if sendkeys can DTRT.

Any help appreciated.

A bit of additional info:

For a variety of poor reasons, some reports get dumped into a mishmash hierarchy of folders, but with consistent naming.  So I want to just search with explorer, they can control-a/control-C/control-v them into their own working folder for further processing.